# Does cobalt RC 11 support Web Audio API

Tags: web-audio-api, cobalt

From my understanding, the Youtube technical requirement for 2017 and 2018 requires support of W3C Web Audio API.
Cobalt is currently not able to run the qual-e web audio web page: http://qual-e.appspot.com/webaudio.html. The video player is not rendered. Also clicking the navigation buttons does not result in sound played and with the following message on the console.

[0917/153645:ERROR:console.cc(62)] [console.error()] Error in loading sound:

Does cobalt currently support Web Audio API?
Does cobalt currently support rendering the webpage http://qual-e.appspot.com/webaudio.html?
Will such a support rely on the starboard audio_sink api or some other api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cobalt supports WebAudio API. This works well with linux-x64x11 reference implementation while navigating the YouTube app(https://youtube.com/tv).

The reason why WebAudio TC does not work is due to the lack of  support which is not YouTube's requirement. We will rewrite the test case once we modify ShakaPlayer to work on Cobalt.